# How to format an unrecognisable external HDD?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I have formated an HDD in linux and my laptop died mid-formatting.

The disk cannot be recognised by windows now.

Output from USB Device Viewer:

```
[Port2] FailedEnumeration :  Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)


Is Port User Connectable:         yes
Is Port Debug Capable:            no
Companion Port Number:            0
Companion Hub Symbolic Link Name: 
Protocols Supported:
 USB 1.1:                         yes
 USB 2.0:                         yes
 USB 3.0:                         no

       ---===>Device Information<===---

ConnectionStatus:                  FailedEnumeration
Current Config Value:              0x00  -> Device Bus Speed: Low
Device Address:                    0x00
Open Pipes:                           0
*!*ERROR:  No open pipes!

          ===>Device Descriptor<===
*!*ERROR:  bLength of 0 incorrect, should be 18
bLength:                           0x00
bDescriptorType:                   0x00
bcdUSB:                          0x0000
bDeviceClass:                      0x00
*!*ERROR:  Device enumeration failure
```

I cannot see the HDD anywhere. When I try to reconnect it I get the following error: 
[ERROR when connecting the HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZVs9.jpg)

Any ideas how I can format this HDD. I don't care much about the data on it.

Comment: Is your HDD recognized in BIOS (as a bootable device, for example) showing correct model/size info?

Comment: I believe a low level format through BIOS can still be done in this case (if HDD is listed in BIOS).

Comment: If you are connecting it using usb interface you would need to connect the hard drive directly to a motherboard, this way the usb controller(s) are removed from the equation, then you should be able to use disk management or Diskpart to format it. You would have to remove the drive from the enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

Is it shown in the command line version of disk manager for windows "diskpart"?

If it is shown you can do the followning:

list disk
select disk #
clean
create partion primary
format fs=ntfs quick

(where # is the number with which diskpart identifies your disk.)

Comment: it does not appear there either